# Octomap in rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, octomap, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build 3d indoor map using rgbd slam package. I am using ros fuerte version. I am confused which package of octomap to be installed for mapping with rgbdslam package. In tutorial, the link is given only for electric version.

Any body have idea about it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39273/octomap-in-rgbdslam/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To install octomap in Fuerte, just run

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-octomap ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping
```

Make sure that there is no other version of octomap_mapping / octomap_server in your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and compile rgbd-slam. It should then compile and link against this installed version of octomap.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-07-19**:
thanks a lot.. it worked for me